# Prevent document event listener from firing?

Tags: javascript

I have `document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onDocument);` so I can detect when a user clicks off something.

But on my button click handler I have:

```
toggleItemActive(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        ....
```

But when I click the button on my iPad, the document touch handler still runs.

How can I allow for clicks on my button without running the document touch handler?

Comment: e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @Learner still fails.

Comment: @panthro Can you please create a snippet for `click` event in the post and tell how it fails?

Comment: did you try it on phone or  chrome dev tools?

Comment: This was tried on an iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Event#preventDefault` but you need to also check the `Event#defaultPrevented` flag in the container if you do.

Example Using `Event#defaultPrevented`

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
  console.log("Container Clicked");
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Test Clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Example without `Event#defaultPrevented`

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Container Clicked");
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Test Clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Example Using `Event#defaultPrevented` (`touchstart` event)

```js
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
  console.log("Container Clicked");
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Test Clicked");
});

var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("touchstart", true, true);
document.querySelector("#test").dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Example that uses both `click` and `touchstart` listener

```js
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
  console.log("Container Clicked");
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Test Clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Example using ignored array

```js
var excludedList = ["test"];

document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  if (excludedList.indexOf(event.target.id) !== -1) return;
  console.log("Container Clicked");
});
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Test Clicked");
});

var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("touchstart", true, true);
document.querySelector("#test").dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Your example works fine, but fails when you try and attach it to the document.

Comment: @panthro - then you should edit your question such that it meets expected standards. Failing to do so has resulted in the wasted effort of those trying to help someone too lazy to write the question properly.

Comment: @panthro, I attached it to the `document` element, there is no change in behaviour

Comment: @nickzoum interesting, you are correct, tested on iPad. Perhaps this has something to do with you using a click in your example, yet i'm using a `touchstart` event on my document listener?

Comment: I tested the same code with `touchstart` [with this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he39g04s/1). It was working fine

Comment: Two possible reasons that would explain your problem are: setting `useCapture` to `true` when doing `document.addEventListener("...",...,true);` or just touching the wrong element

Comment: @nickzoum thanks for the various examples, they do work on the iPad but mine still fails, I suspect because I'm using a `touchstart` event for document and a `click` event for the button.

Comment: Wait, are you using different events for the button and the document? The event passed in each listener is different, so you are preventing the wrong event. Either use the same event by both elements or add some custom code on the the document listener that excludes certain elements.

Comment: Yes, differing events, this is because I can't seem to get a click event to fire on the document on touch devices - any ideas?

Comment: @panthro Updated answer again, you could do what is shown in the last snippet. You could also just add 2 listeners to the button, the normal one for the `click` event and another one on the `touchstart` event just to cancel the event. I would recommend using 2 listeners (check 4th snippet)

Comment: @nickzoum thanks for all your help and extensive examples. You are a credit to this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `this.onDocument` handler, check whether `event.currentTarget` is the button you want to prevent and do nothing.
Some thing like this should work

```
onDocument(e){
  // get access to the target button e.g assuming your button has an id targetButton
  let targetButton = document.querySelector('#targetButton')

  // do no thing if the target button is clicked
  if(e.currentTarget === targetButton){
    return;
  }

  // do whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `touchstart` fires before `click` so you can never know in advance if the touch resolves into a click (it will always fire).

The easiest way to 'fix' your problem is to check in your touchStart event handler what you are dealing with.

```
function onDocumentTouchStart(e){
  if (!e.target.matches('button|a.this-one')) { // refine queryString for exclusions
    // proceed with logging
  }
}
```

Or briefly detach the touchstart event handler when clicking the button. This works but since it uses an async re-attachement it feels a bit dirty.

```js
const onDocumentTouchStart = ()=>console.log('touchstart')

toggleDocumentTouchStart(true)

const button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  toggleDocumentTouchStart(false)
 requestAnimationFrame(toggleDocumentTouchStart.bind(null,true))
})
button.addEventListener('click', ()=>console.log('buttonClick'))

function toggleDocumentTouchStart(add){
 add
  ?document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart)
  :document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart)
}
```

```html
<button>button that prevents</button>
<div>foo</div>
<button>another button</button>
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); has been applied to both the click event and the document touch event, still fails.

Comment: elm.addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault(), {capture: true}) also fails, document listener still fires.